# The stable-homotopy-homology-theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy

Hi

Is there a way to stabilise relative homotopy groups into giving the stable-homotopy-homology-functor?
The fact that the homotopy excision theorem holds for exactly the same kind of pair that occurs in the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms seems to indicate, that this should be possible, doesn't it?

For CW-pairs $(X,A)$ simply applying unreduced suspension repeatedly, taking homotopy groups accordingly (basepoints become unnecessary) and going to the limit works fine, I think. (Though I may have overlooked something once more.)

For a while I thought this approach might just work for arbitrary pairs, however Tom Goodwillie (thankfully) set me straight by pointing out, that this is rubbish: The suspension of a subspace need not even be a subspace of the suspension ( [Suspension of an excisive pair](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84971/suspension-of-an-excisive-pair) ), whence one doesn't even end up with a pair of spaces after suspension.

Has this approach been studied in the literature? My standard textbooks only construct reduced stable homotopy groups and I've been wondering why, ever since first learning about stable homotopy groups. So i would be very happy with a reference and somewhat content with an answer as to why this can't possibly work.

Comment: The stable homotopy groups of the mapping cone of the map of spectra $\Sigma^{\infty}A\rightarrow\Sigma^{\infty}A$ induced by the inclusion $A\subset X$ 

Comment: I mean $\Sigma^\infty A\rightarrow\Sigma^\infty X$

Comment: but that does not stabilize relative homotopy groups, but rather circumvents them, right?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: it replaces relative groups by absolute groups of the cone and then stabilises them instead. How is that not circumventing?

Comment: Because classical relative homotopy groups are ordinary homotopy groups of the homotopy fiber of the inclusion

Comment: hmm  I also think of that as circumventing; for me they are given by maps and homotopies of pairs...

Comment: Whatever approach you like, what I say is not circumventing, it's simply true! :-)

Comment: and yet does not answer my question...    you'd need basepoints for the spectra anyway, don't you?

Comment: Don't you need them for relative homotopy groups???

Comment: once you suspend a couple of times, you no longer do: if i have not overlooked anything, then the group structure becomes canonical on unpointed maps once everything is simply connected.

Comment: More or less the same for spectra

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it appears to be answered in the comments, and the system will periodically bump this unless we close it.